# WifiLock under-locked my_lock

Tags: skmaps

I'm tring to download an offline map pack. Trying to reverse engineer the example project from the skobbler support website, however when trying to start a download the download manager crashes.

What my usecase is: show a list of available countries (within the EUR continent) and make the user select a single one, and that will be downloaded at that time. So far I have  gotten a list where those options are available. Upon selecting an item (and starting the download) it crashes.

For the sake of the question I commented out some things.

Relevant code:

```
// Get the information about where to obtain the files from
SKPackageURLInfo urlInfo = SKPackageManager.getInstance().getURLInfoForPackageWithCode(pack.packageCode);

// Steps: SKM, ZIP, TXG
List<SKToolsFileDownloadStep> downloadSteps = new ArrayList<>();
downloadSteps.add(new SKToolsFileDownloadStep(urlInfo.getMapURL(), pack.file, pack.skmsize)); // SKM
//downloadSteps.add();  // TODO ZIP
//downloadSteps.add()); // TODO TXG

List<SKToolsDownloadItem> downloadItems = new ArrayList<>(1);
downloadItems.add(new SKToolsDownloadItem(pack.packageCode, downloadSteps, SKToolsDownloadItem.QUEUED, true, true));

mDownloadManager.startDownload(downloadItems); // This is where the crash is
```

I am noticing a running download, since the onDownloadProgress() is getting triggered (callback from the manager). However the SKToolsDownloadItem that it takes as a parameter says that the stepIndex starts at 0. I don't know how this can be, since I manually put that at (byte) 0, just like the example does.

Also, the logs throw a warning on SingleClientConnManager, telling me:

```
Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
```

This is code that gets called from within the manager somewhere. I am thinking there is some vital setup steps missing from the documentation and the example project.

Comment: Could I ask why do you need to modify the provided downloadManager? Is there any functionality not present? What would be the desired use case?

Comment: I don't want to mofify it. I want to use it, but the wifi lock keeps throwing the exception "RuntimeException: WifiLock under-locked my_lock". The code that I provided is just the creation of the items that get sent to the downloadManager.

Comment: Testing the open source demo -the download of a package (including the skm, txg and zip files) using the SKToolsDownloadManager -works normally. The map is available offline and also the offline address search option for the downloaded package. Tested on a Nexus 5 device with Android version 5.1. Check this code snippet (with some comments describing what happens at each step) for testing the download functionality: http://pastebin.com/AbgSL6YQ

Comment: @SylviA I have a similar problem. I just copy and paste all your code above and run it. And every time my app is crashed in releaseResourcesWhenDownloadThreadFinishes() method, at this line "wifiLock.release();". Error text is "java.lang.RuntimeException: WifiLock under-locked my_lock". Please could you help me what to do or what to check? Thanks!

Comment: @SylviA I solved my problem. In SKToolsDownloadPerformer WifiLock is created but never acquired. So release() method throws an exception. So the solution is to check isHeld() before do any release(), or to add acquire() right after creating the lock.

Comment: We will fix the problem in the next SDK demo